# bootstrap 4 > css selectors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm new to CSS and Bootstrap so please dumb this down for me. I have a nav bar with a custom class for formatting:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-custom navbar-toggleable-sm" role="navigation" id="NavContainer">
```

Since I'm learning I figure I best move to BS4 now rather than continue to learn BS3 which will soon be out of date, though I appreciate BS4 is currently in alpha stage..

I understand that BS4 has dropped nearly all > selectors in favour of styling via un-nested classes. My BS3 code refered to links on the navbar with the nested syntax:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #717171;
  padding-top:8px;
}
```

How do I convert this to BS4 **for the nav bar only** i.e. not all links on the page? I've read about using Grunt to recompile to Sass but frankly it's over my head. Is there any way to do this in basic CSS or do I need to learn about Sass / Grunt (nb: I'm not looking to be a developer, just making a simple site for myself)?

Here are the different things I've tried:

```
.nav-link {
  color: #227447;
}
```

---

```
.nav-link a:hover, .nav-link a:hover{
  color: #227447;
}
```

---

```
.navbar-custom .nav-link a:hover, .nav-link a:focus{
  color: #227447;
}
```

---

Comment: I don't understand why you are excluding the solution you already have. Why should the fact that BS4 doesn't want to use `>` mean that you don't get to?

Comment: @11684 because it doesn't work in BS4... not sure what's confusing there

Comment: "It doesn't work in BS4"? What exactly happens? What's confusing here is that I thought BS4 wouldn't alter the DOM structure, in which case the fact that you are using BS4 would have no effect on which CSS selectors you can and cannot use. I based this on my experience with an older bootstrap version, though, so I might be mistaken.

Comment: Also, Sass is compiled to (drumroll) CSS, so if this is possible using Grunt/Sass, a pure CSS solution also exists.

Comment: @11684 They've just dropped those selectors: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#navs the css doesn't affect the links in any way with my current code

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it says Bootstrap stopped using this selector _in their codebase_. The selector itself is part of CSS, the fact that they don't use it doesn't mean you can't. I assume they stopped using it as an optimisation (it is relatively slow, IIRC). Could you post your HTML as well? Maybe the selector just doesn't match any element in your markup.

Comment: And what happens if you use the selector `.nav-link` instead? (Taken from the third point of the paragraph you linked to.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that is not working either, I'll update the post

Comment: There are two more pieces of information that would help in diagnosing the problem: your HTML markup (to check if the selectors match anything) and the eventual DOM structure (to see if Bootstrap breaks your selectors by changing the DOM). You can find the latter in the development tools in your browser, generally under "inspect element" in the ctrl-click/right click menu (obviously this is browser-dependent). It should show you HTML markup representing the current state of the DOM (rather than just the source – unless nothing was changed).